# Run http.server on startup with crontab

Tags: python, cron, startup, launch

I'm writing a digital menu board and displaying it on a 50" TV.

Using python3 -m http.server in HTML files location.

I want the menu to launch on startup. Current script that is in crontab does the following. It's very simple.

1. cd 'dir'
2. sudo python3 -m http.server 443 &
3. chromium-browser 0.0.0.0:443 --start-fullscreen

I can see crontab has ran @reboot calls but chromium never launches.

Ignore hideous code, it's just to get this thing working.

I've tried running the file from crontab, init.d (update-rc), even tried running the file from /etc/profile in desperation.

```
import os

os.chdir('//home//pi//Desktop//TotalMenu')
os.system('sudo python3 -m http.server 443 &')
os.system('chromium-browser 0.0.0.0:443 --start-fullscreen')
```

Comment: When you use `sudo` command while running `http.server`, where are you entering the `password`?

Comment: I've given pi pi   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL in sudoers - VERY bad practice I know. This was after trying to pass the script and /usr/bin/python3 as a NOPASSWD flag

Comment: What's happening if you don't give `sudo` in the command?

Comment: Permission Denied